# Accidentaly organized two job interviews for overlapping, how to communicate to minimize loss?

Tags: interviewing

Thus, the problem is that I mistakenly changed a week row in my calendar. And now, I have two job interviews (by different companies), on the same time.

Unfortunately, I acknowledged soon my presence by both companies.

What could I do now to minimize the face loss?

*Extension:* They gave me multiple datetime proposals to let me choose, which is for me okay. This selection gone bad.

*Extension:* Please don't sign this as a duplicate, because this question is focusing not on the organizing part, but on the face loss avoidance.

Comment: Different question, but same answer - [Two interviews at once](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/41887/two-interviews-at-once)

Comment: @DavidK There is a difference: this time I risk a hard face loss by at least one of the companies, because of my terrible mistake.

Comment: @user8558 The other questions contains the only viable answer to this issue. You'll have to reschedule with the job that either interests you less or you feel you have a much less of a chance of getting

Comment: @user8558 How do you know that you will face a 'hard face loss' from one of the companies?  This is *very* relevant to answering your question - if one company cannot flex the least on your interview, obviously you should reschedule with the *other* company instead.

Comment: @Zibbobz Because I want now to reschedule what I previously acknowledged. I annoy their HR department, my (maybe) project leader and my (maybe) department leader. They are important persons, a simple wannabe-employee simply can't start by the rescheduling of their calendar.

Comment: @user8558 Scheduling interviews is *their job*, and rescheduling them to accommodate their prospective employees is *also* their job.  You will annoy them far more by not bringing up this conflict and wasting people's time than you would with simply asking them to reschedule.  The amount of annoyance in rescheduling is minor, and **is a part of HR's job** that you should not feel guilty about having them do.  **It is perfectly acceptable to ask HR to reschedule your interview**.  They won't necessarily be able to if there's no other time for it, but you stand to lose very little by asking.

Comment: @Zibbobz Yes, but in this case they gave me 3 datetime proposals and I choosed badly... :-(

Comment: @user8558 That's fine.  You're really overestimating how much of an issue this is.  And you need to consider that if you don't ask to reschedule now, it will be *more* inconvenient to your potential boss and HR. The most polite thing you can do to them is own up to the mistake (don't mention another interview - just that you made a scheduling mistake) and ask to reschedule, sooner rather than later, so that they can adjust their own schedule with the least amount of heartache.

Comment: @Zibbobz This is what I did! Thank you very much. (They let me felt, that they are not happy, but I will get a new schedule soon.)

Comment: I felt it only dangerous, because I choosen the date and time from 3 options which the HR gave me. Now I needed to talk to them again and say, "uhm sorry it is not so good despite I said earlier it will be okay"...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't go to both of these interviews - it's impossible to be in two places at once.  You will have to reschedule one of them.

You do not need to mention that you are rescheduling because of another interview - just pick a company and tell them you have an appointment you can't miss, and ask them to reschedule.  If they refuse, ask the other company if *they* can reschedule.

If neither company will reschedule, call and cancel the interview you will miss the least - or just don't show up for it, if you cannot handle cancelling the interview.  But if neither one of them will reschedule, it is the polite thing to do to cancel at least one so that you leave them on good terms.

Call as soon as possible - it improves the company's ability to reschedule for you, and is much more courteous and convenient to their needs as well.

---

As for saving face, the effect of asking to re-schedule an interview is **very minimal** in terms of losing respect from your employer, both for the interviewer and for the HR department.  You should be courteous and polite in requesting to re-schedule, understanding if they cannot accommodate your schedule, and apologize for the inconvenience at most.

This really isn't a huge issue - scheduling mishaps happen all the time.  It's better to own up to it now and ask to reschedule than it is to stew over the mistake and make things *more* difficult for HR and your potential boss by not correcting the mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You call the first company and say "I have an interview on Monday at 3pm. Unfortunately, I received another rather important appointment at the exact same time. I can come to the interview, but it would really help me if we could move it to a different time". Then you see what the reaction is. The person doing the interview might be quite happy doing it in the morning, or the next day, or the day before, and you are fine. If not, tell them that you will come to the interview and call the second company with the same story.

If neither interview can be moved, you decide which one you'd rather go to, call the other and say that unfortunately you can't come. You *could* not call them, in case the other interview is cancelled on the last minute. If one can be moved but not the other, it is a judgement call whether this is coincidence or whether one company is generally more flexible and therefore better to work with.

Comment: They gave me multiple datetime proposals, I choosed badly from them.

Comment: @user8558 Then it is time to correct that by asking to re-schedule.

Comment: @Zibbobz If I say them that I want to reschedule my interview because of _another_ interview from _another_ company, maybe it won't be the best first impression, don't you think?

Comment: @user8558 Probably not, and you don't *have* to say that - you could just tell them you need to reschedule because of another 'appointment' - you don't *have* to say it's another interview.  It isn't really a huge deal - hiring managers know that prospective employees might have multiple interviews going on, and they won't hold a grudge over that.  But you don't even have to bring it up to ask them to reschedule.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do at such a time is to try to reschedule one of them on  different time or a different date. You can request the concerned authority that you would need a rescheduling. Show them that you are keen on taking that interview and if they could possibly reschedule at a time suitable to them.

Make clear that it is due to something that is urgent or something that has come up and needs immediate attention or simple state that you would be unavailable on the said date due to a thing beyond your control and request for a change in time.

Request such a change at the place you feel is more flexible, or where you are comparatively less keen.